# Pycharm: Цвет подчеркивания PEP8

Tags: ide, pycharm

Здравствуйте. Как изменить в pycharm цвет которым подчеркиваются стилистические ошибки PEP8, если такая возможность вообще имеется? Хочу чтобы эта волнистая линия была, например, ярко-красной. 
 По дефолту цвет линии у меня серый на сером фоне такой, что я даже не сразу понял что там вообще что-то подчеркнуто. Скорее всего где-то в Editor → Colors & Fonts, но где точно? Я только изучаю Пайтон, и хочу сразу приучаться кодить красиво))

Comment: Settings - Editor - Colors & Font - General - Errors and Warnings - Error

Comment: не совсем то. Во-первых это подчеркивание итак у меня было выставлено ярким красным цветом. А во-вторых - его изменение никак не затрагивает ошибки подчеркнутые PEP8

Answer (score 2):

Вот нужный параметр: Settings - Editor - Colors & Font - General - Errors and Warnings - Weak Warning